# Parse response in json

Tags: json, parsing

how can i parse below response in Json object.

```
ResponseInforamtion({
"Name": "Test",
"Address": "Test Address",
"City": "Test City"
});
```

i tried with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) but didn't work as this is not a right json response . But this response is coming from third party API

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert a sting into valid JS.